# Data is not getting inserted into SQL Server database in orderly manner from datatable vb.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, datatable, sql-insert

I am developing one migration utility to transfer data from one table to another using vb.net because I need to make some changes in data and then insert it into another table, while doing this I came to a point where I am inserting data into sql server db from data table using loop through data table, but when I go to SQL Server and check that data is there or not, its not in order by Srno, this is the first time i am seeing this kind of thing, Before inserting the data I am displaying the data in DataGridView and it is showing completely fine in it but as soon as i insert the data from data table to SQL Server DB it does not get saved in order as that is displaying in DataGridView

**Note**: I tried to loop through DataGridView as well but it is doing the same thing.

Please check the following code for understanding, I've 4500 records need to be migrated

```vb
If finalDT.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        For Each q In finalDT.Rows
            'MessageBox.Show(q.item("ID").ToString + q.item("ODate").ToString + q.item("WDate").ToString)
            id = q.item("ID")
            odate = q.item("Odate")
            wdate = q.item("WDate")
            intime = q.item("WDatetime")
            outtime = q.item("ODatetime")
            qry = "insert into weight3 values ('" & id & "','" & odate & "','" & wdate & "','" & intime & "','" & outtime & "')"

            updateWt(qry) - Insert QRY Goes for operation

        Next
    End If
```

Please check this image to see how the data is getting inserted.

[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w024.jpg)

Rest of the details are as follow,

Database schema

```
Srno    int 

Odate   datetime    
Wdatetime   datetime    
intime  nvarchar(50)    
outtime nvarchar(50)
```

Data table

```
finalDT.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
finalDT.Columns.Add("ODate", GetType(String))
finalDT.Columns.Add("WDate", GetType(String))
finalDT.Columns.Add("WDateTime", GetType(String))
finalDT.Columns.Add("ODateTime", GetType(String))
```

Comment: Hi Marc_s, tried to perform the same operation using order by as well, but did not worked

Comment: Okay Mark so how can i perform the same operation while inserting, because as you might have seen the screen shot, I am not getting any clue to insert it into manner

Comment: Okay Thanks Mark_S I understood well..!

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is basically **impossible**, since a relational database table **does NOT have** any inherent ordering - there's no way to insert data "in an ordered fashion" since the table itself is not ordered by design.

The only way to get ordering in a relational database is by `SELECT`ing from your database table and specifying an explicit `ORDER BY` clause while doing so - in this case, you get back your data in the orderly fashion you've defined.

But there's no way in a relational database to "order the table" by any key or combination of keys or anything - the database table itself is **UNORDERED** - and that's by design.